# Difference between LLDP and LLDP-MED

Tags: ethernet, voip, lldp

What is the difference between LLDP and LLDP-MED? Is LLDP-MED an add-on to LLDP or something completely different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Media Endpoint Discovery is an enhancement of LLDP, known as LLDP-MED, that provides the following facilities:

- Auto-discovery of LAN policies (such as VLAN, Layer 2 Priority and Differentiated services (Diffserv) settings) enabling plug and play networking.
- Device location discovery to allow creation of location databases and, in the case of Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP), Enhanced 911 services.
- Extended and automated power management of Power over Ethernet (PoE) end points.
- Inventory management, allowing network administrators to track their network devices, and determine their characteristics (manufacturer, software and hardware versions, serial or asset number).

The LLDP-MED protocol extension was formally approved and published as the standard ANSI/TIA-1057 by the Telecommunications Industry Association (TIA) in April 2006.

Answer (score 7):

Link Layer Discovery (IEEE-802.1AB-2005) provides the base capabilities for discovery, but was seen as insufficent for IP Telephony and Real Time Video. So the LLDP-MED initiative was formed by HP, Mitel and Avaya in 2004. *What does LLDP-MED provide?*

- **Interoperability** > provide vendor independent management capabilities, enabling different convergence endpoints to interoperate on one network.
- **Automatic deployment of convergence network policies** > voice VLAN, Layer 2 and DSCP QoS policies.
- **Location Services, including Emergency Call Services** > enablement of E-911, 999, 112for IP Telephony through physical location.
- **Detailed Inventory Management Capabilities** > location information and accurate topology is made available. Switch acts as proxy to collect inventory, as few endpoints support SNMP.
- **Advanced PoE** > Fine grain power management to support more phones per switch. Backup power conservation to extend UPS battery life during disasters.
- **IP Telephony network troubleshooting** > detect incorrect voice VLAN, QoS and duplex mismatch.

Further, LLDP-MED provides a *fast start* behaviour which is very important for IP telephony, this means at Startup the endpoints will initially advertise at a faster rate for a limited time.